# Inheritance and default constructor in perl

Tags: perl, oop, inheritance

I have the following code :-

```
package A;

sub new{
 //constructor for A
}

sub hello{
 print "Hello A";
}

1;

package B;
use base qw(A);

sub hello{
 print "Hello B";
}

1;
```

My question is how can I instantiate B i.e. my $b = B->new(), without giving a constructor to B, what changes do I need to do in A to achieve this. Is this possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Use this as `A`'s `new` method:

```
sub new {
    my ($cls, @args) = @_;
    # ...
    my $obj = ...;  # populate this
    bless $obj, $cls;
}
```

The key is that when using `B->new`, the first argument is `B` (which I bound to `$cls` in my example). So if you call `bless` using `$cls`, the object will be blessed with the correct package.

Comment: sub new{
  my $self = {};
  my $arg = shift;
  my $class = ref($arg) || $arg;
  printf("\n\tA's constructor\n");
  $self->{NAME} = "A";
  bless($self,$class);
  return $self;
}

Comment: Please suggest a change in the above method

Comment: @AAB: So change all references to `A` in your code into references to `$class`. e.g., `printf("$class's constructor")`, and `$self->{NAME} = $class`, if you want.

Comment: I tried using the following in my code :- my $a = A->new() and my $b = B->new() but i get the following error on $b = B->new() it says Can't locate object method "new" via package "B"

Comment: @AAB, There is already a B module that comes with Perl. Avoid that name. It leads to weird errors.

Answer (score 3):

In line with Chris' answer, your code should now look like:

```
package A;
sub new{
    my ( $class ) = @_;
    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $class;
}
sub hello{
    print "Hello A";
}

package B;
use base qw(A);
sub hello{
    print "Hello B";
}

package main;
my $b = B->new;
$b->hello;
```

`B` simply inherits `A`'s constructor.

Comment: I tried using the above code still I tend to get the same error saying that the Can't locate object method new via package B